# Help Deriving Kinematic Equations with Drag Element

Tags: integration, physics, simulation, kinematics

Please see Charles Hudgins answer below for a beautiful solution.

I have encountered a problem that I'm unsure if I will be able to solve myself. I've spent countless hours spinning my wheels on this and I've begun to wonder if it's even possible (or logical) what I am trying to do.

The nature of the problem is I have a simulation of an object in motion that is both decelerating and experiencing a drag force that is subject to the object's velocity at any given point in time. I want to find the required time for the object to come to a complete stop (TTS). The equation to calculate the velocity of an object from frame-to-frame is:

$$
V_f = (V_i + at)(1 - rt)
$$
$V_f$ is the next simulation step velocity, $V_i$ is the current simulation step velocity, $a$ is a constant acceleration on the object (slowing down), $r$ is the drag coefficient (between $0$ and $1$), and $t$ is the simulation time step (generally $0.02$ seconds). Whenever the drag coefficient is $0$, this model reduces to Newton's first law of motion $V_f = V_i + at$. I am able to reliably use all of Newton's equations of motion to solve for the time to stop with ease.

Now when the drag coefficient is not $0$ obviously many things change. The main change is that the drag coefficient modifies the velocity at every given point in time. At any given point I know $V_i$, $a$, and $r$. It seemed obvious to me that plugging in $0$ for $V_f$ and then solving for $t$ would get the correct result but it is very wrong.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to derive the time to stop given this equation? And / or sanity check me about whether or not this is feasible given the time-step type of simulation. Since Newton's laws work without drag, I am optimistic there is a continuous solution that includes drag. I have tried integrating to be able to solve over a given range, but it gets weird because of the fact that the drag coefficient is subject to instantaneous velocity.

Note - I have implemented an iterative solver that simply projects this equation out, but for most of my use cases, this is not ideal due to the sheer amount of simulations that are happening at any given time.  I have included the simulation (which works) below for reference. I would much prefer to have an integral or something to solve in an absolute manner. Cubic and/or Quartic is no problem.

```
    private float SimulateTimeToStop(float vi, float a, float r, float timeStep)
    {
        var tts = 0f;

        while(vi > 0)
        {
            vi = (vi + a * timeStep) * (1 - r * timeStep);
            tts += timeStep;
        }

        return tts;
    }
```

Here are some (simualated) sample results.

Scenario 1:
Vi = 15,
r = 0.5,
a = -6

TTS = 1.64 seconds

Scenario 2:
Vi = 45,
r = 1,
a = -15

TTS = 1.4 seconds

Scenario 3:
Vi = 28,
r = 0.75
a = -3;

TTS = 2.78 seconds

Scenario 4:
Vi = 35,
r = 0.85,
a = -5

TTS ??

Comment: This is a very weird kinematic model.  $V_f = V_i + t(a - art - rV_i)$, so somehow the drag force is also attenuating the acceleration.  Are you sure you wouldn't be happier with $V_f = V_i + t(a - rV_i)$ so the drag now matches your words: "a drag force that is subject to the object's velocity at any given point in time"?

Answer (score 1):

Set $V_f = v + dv$ and $V_i = v$. Then
$$
v + dv = (v + adt)(1 - rdt)
$$
Which yields
$$
v + dv = v - rvdt + adt + O(dt^2)
$$
So
$$
dv = (a - rv)dt + O(dt^2)
$$
Which yields the differential equation
$$
\frac{dv}{dt} = a - rv
$$
Which integrates to
$$
v = \frac{1}{r} (a - Ce^{-rt})
$$
for some constant $C$.

Comment: Charles, I must be especially dense here. I am still struggling to find the time to stop given your derivation here. I was able to follow it, but I am not using it properly. In my simulation, an object with v = 15, r = 1, and a = -6 takes approximately 1.26 seconds to stop. The same object with r = 0.5 takes 1.64 seconds to stop. I'm not able to recreate these numbers at all with the above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think you're doing anything wrong per se. You'll find that the object stops as soon as $a = Ce^{-rt}$. However, in the long run, (i.e. as $t \to \infty$), we'll have $v \to \frac{a}{r}$, which is not $0$ in general.

Comment: If $v_0$ is the initial velocity, you can check that we have $C = a - rv_0$. So that the object stops  when $a = (a - rv_0)e^{-rt}$. That is, when $t = -\frac{1}{r}\log(\frac{a}{a - rv_0})$. You can check if your results match this expression. Note that we'll only getting a stopping time with $t > 0$ if $a < a - rv_0$, i.e. if $rv_0 < 0$.

Comment: *we'll only get a stopping time with $t > 0$ if $rv_0 < 0$.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're getting something that disagrees with the derivation because your timesteps are not infinitesimal. In particular, your $dt^2$ terms are not actually negligible.

Comment: Sorry to chain comments, but I have to correct an error in my previous comment. We can rewrite the stop time as $t = \frac{1}{r} \log(1 - \frac{rv_0}{a})$. To have stop time $t > 0$, we need $\frac{rv_0}{a} < 0$. I checked your answer with $v = 15$, $r = 1$, and $a = -6$, and I get $t = 1.25$ is the stopping time.

Comment: Charles, I am a bit in disbelief that you made this so elegant. This is phenomenal. I have plugged this in and it works flawlessly. I cannot thank you enough, this has been a huge problem for me for (dare I say) months and just like that it's solved.

Comment: I am going to redact my question above and reword it. I went ahead and took a stab at taking this one step further. Spoiler alert, I didn't, but here's where I got. Given TTS is obtainable, now I'm after capturing the actual distance to stop (DTS). To start I ran a few simulations to baseline results against.

Vi = 15
a = -6
r = 1

DTS = 7.32

Vi = 45
a = -9
r = 0.65

DTS = 37.89

The first thing I notice here is that t seems like it shouldn't be a part of the equation at all.  Similar to the kinematic equation Vf^2 = Vi^2 + 2 * a * d. I might already be off my rocker here

Comment: Or alternatively we calculate t, and then solve for DTS with t. I don't know enough tricks to weed out t from the above integration so I will work with the latter.

Since there already exists the equation for velocity at a given point in time (V = 1/r (a - Ce^-rt)), It seems to me integrating this with respect to t would give a distance traveled, or Pf-Pi where P is position.

Would it be reasonable to consider V as dP/dT, and then just integrate the right side with respect to t? Or will something need to be done to C1 given that it involves Vi as well?

Comment: When I integrated the above I ultimately got:

S = (a*r*t + C(e^-rt - 1)) / r^2.

Given the above scenarios, I get 7.4834m and 38.408m respectively. They seem slightly off from what I am simulating though, but are definitely tracking

Comment: Yes, it should be as simple as integrating the expression against time. I get a different answer, however. See if you can get the expression $x = \frac{1}{r^2} (art + Ce^{-rt}) + D$ for some constant $D$. Remember you can always differentiate to check if you've integrated properly.

Comment: I think what I am failing to grasp is what the D constant is in this case. Otherwise everything else looks great

Comment: You know $C = a - rv_0$. Let $x_0$ be the initial position. Plug in $x_0$ for $x$ and $0$ for $t$ and solve for $D$.